# Bluetooth icon issues

Tags: bluetooth

I can actually use my BT keyboard to select an OS at start up.
Once Ubuntu starts and I try to search for devices they will flash in the window momentarily and not connect and then the menu bar bluetooth icon shows a lock, so I believe bluetooth  is being blocked by something as soon as it discovers any devices.
Late 2011 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I had to hold the right side button on both the keyboard and the track pad until they show up in the **Add Device** screen.

The keyboard was easy to set up.

The track pad would not pair the first 2 times, but I selected the 0000 pin option and 2 more times and it finally worked.

I find that I have to unplug my usb mouse for the track pad to work properly. I shut down and rebooted... All is Well :-).

The BT icon shows up with the lock symbol still, but when I add a device it goes away then comes back after it has paired.